# Can a vacuum act as a good electrical insulator?

Tags: charge, electrical-resistance, voltage, vacuum

Assume two positively charged plates have voltages $V_1$ and $V_2$ and are separated by a distance $d$. Between the plates, there is a strong vacuum (not a perfect vacuum because that's practically impossible in a laboratory setting.)

Paschen's law describes the "breakdown voltage" of any strong vacuum. My question is this: would it matter what the absolute charge is of either plate? The $\Delta V$ between the plates is $V_2-V_1$. Would strongly positively charging both plates ($1 \ \text{kV}$ or more) make any difference in the ability of the vacuum to resist a flow of electrons from one plate to the other? I feel that any remaining gas molecules in the vacuum would become electrically charged as well, and would thus avoid contacting either wall - making it an even better electrical insulator.

Answer (score 1):

From an electrical engineering perspective, yes, a near-vacuum is an excellent insulator.

Vacuum circuit breakers are used precisely for this reason, to extinguish the arc from separating contacts:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_interrupter

Answer (score 0):

The vacuum has $440\Omega$, Ohms, of resistance. This comes about from the ratio of the electric field to the magnetic field $Z~=~\frac{|E|}{|B|}$. The standard Ohms' law is $V~=~IR$ and the electric field has units of $volts/meter$ and the magnetic field has units $Webers~=~amp/m$. The ratio of the electric field to magnetic field is then an impedance.

If you have a dipole antenna that generates electromagnetic waves then a certain amount of energy is being sent into space. From the perspective of the circuit the antenna has this impedance reflected in the energy sent into space. Using the energy of the electric field ${\cal E}~=~\frac{1}{2}E^2 it is not hard to see the Ohms law result for power, which is the rate energy is sent into space.

Then at $440\Omega$ the vacuum is a partial insulator. Electrons can travel through space.

Comment: AFAIK $Z_0 \approx 377 \Omega$. Might you have made an arithmetic error or mis-remembered?

Comment: What would happen if a Van der Graaf generator was in vacuum? How much would you be able to charge it?

Comment: It is $Z = 377\Omega$, and I mis-remembered. A Vad der Graaf would work the same in a vacuum.

Answer (score 0):

The thing to look for is [vacuum breakdown](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-1-4899-2130-7_8.pdf). In a strong (1+ GV/m) electric field an electron can tunnel away from the cathode, accelerating to the anode and hitting with a lot of energy that ionizes some atoms. Now they have an excuse to jump across, releasing even more ions. [The exact field needed depends on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_electron_emission) the work function of the material, how smooth the surface is, and temperature.

At $10^{12}$ V/m the Schwinger limit starts to bite and pair production will begin. But the above issue will likely dominate long before it.